# helper in ember is receiving "undefined"

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a component in ember that contains two separate columns. I am using a helper to take the array and split that array into two, displaying evens on the first column and odds on the left. In the console it shows that the helper is receiving an undefined object.

index.hbs:

```
<div class="row" style="padding:0% 3%">
    {{component numbers=model}}
</div>
```

index.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('number');
    }
});
```

component.hbs (component with two columns):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-6 columns">
{{#each (twoColumns numbers 1) as |number|}}
    <h3><b>{{number.value}}</b></h3>
    <h6>{{number.title}}</h6>
{{/each}}
</div>
{{#each (twoColumns numbers 2) as |number|}}
    <h3><b>{{number.value}}</b></h3>
    <h6>{{number.title}}</h6>
{{/each}}
</div>
</div>
```

twoColumns.js (the helper):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function twoColumns(params) {
  let arrayToSplit = params[0];
  let column = params[1];
  Ember.Logger.info(arrayToSplit); //this prints an empty array
  var i;
  var col1 = [];
  var col2 = [];
  for(i=0; i<arrayToSplit.length; i+=1) {
      if(i%2==0) {
          col1.push(byTheNumbers[i]);
      } else {
          col2.push(byTheNumbers[i]);
      }
  }
  if (column == 1) {
    return col1;
  } else {
    return col2;
  }
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(twoColumns);
```

Also if I do the following, all the elements in the array display fine:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 columns">
{{#each numbers as |number|}}
    <h3><b>{{number.value}}</b></h3>
    <h6>{{number.title}}</h6>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have done this way by using component, in component you can write these computed properties and use in component.hbs.

```
evenItems: Ember.computed('numbers.[]',  function() {
     return this.get('numbers').filter(function(num){ return num.value % 2 === 0 })
 }),

 oddItems: Ember.computed('numbers.[]',  function(number) {
     return this.get('numbers').filter(function(num){ return num.value % 2 !== 0 ;})
 })
```

you can check here https://ember-twiddle.com/fc3e3e85c1a25fea6865d36822c45864?openFiles=components.even-odd.js%2Ctemplates.components.even-odd.hbs